# Count of id with change generates wrong values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df which looks like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'api_spec_id': [213, 213, 213, 345, 345, 345, 678, 678, 678, 123, 123],
    'type': ['BR', 'BR', 'NBR', 'NBR', 'NBR', 'NBR', 'BR', 'BR', 'BR', 'BR', 'BR']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I am trying to count 4 cases, one where every for all rows in `api_spec_id`,the `type= BR` and second where for atleast one row in `api_spec_id`, `the type is BR`.

This is the code I am working with but it seems wrong as it is generating the same output for the last two:

```py
import pandas as pd

at_least_one_breaking_change = df[df['type'] == 'BR']['api_spec_id'].nunique()

all_commits_including_breaking = df.groupby('api_spec_id').apply(lambda x: 'NBR' not in x['type'].unique()) \
                                .sum()

at_least_one_non_breaking_change = df[df['type'] == 'NBR']['api_spec_id'].nunique()

all_commits_including_non_breaking = df.groupby('api_spec_id').apply(lambda x: 'BR' not in x['type'].unique()) \
                                    .sum()
```

The expected output for the sample df I sent will be:

```py
at_least_one_breaking_change = 3
all_commits_including_breaking = 3
at_least_one_non_breaking_change = 2
all_commits_including_non_breaking = 1
```

I am a bit stuck on this and any suggestions or ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you also included the expected outputs. Your example gives me: `at_least_one_non_breaking_change=2` and `all_commits_including_non_breaking=4`

Comment: The first one is right the second should be 1 since I want to count only the api_spec_id where all rows have type=NBR. I am sorry for not adding the expected output previously

Comment: I get `all_commits_including_non_breaking=1` with the updated edit.

Comment: It also looks like perhaps value_counts would be a useful starting point to get this information: `df.groupby('api_spec_id').value_counts()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `pd.crosstab`:

```
m = pd.crosstab(df['api_spec_id'], df['type']).astype(bool)

at_least_one_breaking_change = sum(m['BR'])
all_commits_including_breaking = sum(m['BR'] & ~m['NBR'])

at_least_one_non_breaking_change = sum(m['NBR'])
all_commits_including_non_breaking = sum(m['NBR'] & ~m['BR'])
```

Output:

```
>>> at_least_one_breaking_change
3

>>> all_commits_including_breaking
2

>>> at_least_one_non_breaking_change
2

>>> all_commits_including_non_breaking
1

>>> m
type            BR    NBR
api_spec_id              
123           True  False
213           True   True
345          False   True
678           True  False
```

Comment: However I don't understand why `all_commits_including_breaking` should be 3 and not 2? But it doesn't matter with this matrix you can compute your 4 variables with boolean operations

Comment: I am not sure how to do it for the other two cases, yes you are right it indeed should be 2, i missed the NBR for id 213

Comment: Finally what I understand is `all_commits_including_breaking` is something like `all_commits_including_only_breaking`. I'm right? Else `at_least_one_breaking_change` will always equal to `all_commits_including_breaking`. As I already said with this boolean matrix you can extract all counting information.

Comment: yes that was happening all commits means all rows have BR in them

Answer (score 0):

I have seen and run your code it's output is :

[image: output of your code]

Conditions in this code are bit wrong.

Look at the updates,

```
import pandas as pd


at_least_one_breaking_change = df[df['type'] == 'BR']['api_spec_id'].nunique()

all_commits_including_breaking = df.groupby('api_spec_id').apply(lambda x: 'NBR' in x['type'].unique()) \
                                .sum()

at_least_one_non_breaking_change = df[df['type'] == 'NBR']['api_spec_id'].nunique()

all_commits_including_non_breaking = df.groupby('api_spec_id').apply(lambda x: 'Breaking' in x['type'].unique()) \
                                    .sum()
```

Also, there is no type of `"Breaking"`.

Comment: I checked and updated the code i put it the "Breaking" by mistake. yes it is generating the wrong output nevertheless, i am not sure why

Comment: Can you cross-check that NBR and BR positions I guess it has some issues with the logic.